# IOS animation, repeat sequence

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a sequence of animation to show three different text of UILabel with transform.

```
    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        label.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!!!", name];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
       // code to run when animation completes
       // (in this case, another animation:)
      label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.0, 0.0);
      [UIImageView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
          label.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
          label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!!!", name1];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
          [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:0
             animations:^{
                               label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.0, 0.0);
               label.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
               label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", name3];
             }
           completion:^(BOOL finished){
           }];
        }];
    }];
```

May I know how to repeat this sequence of animations? Put UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat on the outmost animation does not help.

**Edited: thanks for the solution from Matt, the code changes to**

```
   CABasicAnimation *animation1 = [CABasicAnimation animation];
   label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@!!!", name];
   animation1.keyPath = @"transform.scale";
   animation1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
   animation1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
   animation1.duration = 2;


   CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animation];
   UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:120.0];
   int length = (int)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", balance].length;
   NSString *pointString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"welcome %@", name2];
   label.text = pointString;
   animation2.keyPath = @"transform.scale";
   animation2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
   animation2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
   animation2.duration = 2;
   animation2.beginTime = animation1.duration - 0.1;

   CAAnimationGroup *group = [[CAAnimationGroup alloc] init];
   [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:animation1, animation2,nil]];
   group.duration = animation1.duration + animation2.duration;
   [label.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"basic"];
```

May I know how to set the different text on the UIlabel for different animation? The code below does not work. The text change which should have happened when animation2 starts happens before animation1 starts, so animation1 shows the animation2's text.

Regards
Hammer

Comment: put it in a for loop?

Comment: What happens when you use UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat?

Comment: Did you want to repeat a fixed number of times, or forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to wrestle with view animation, which is a convenient front end for Core Animation — until it's not. It will be *much* easier if you would write a grouped animation directly at the Core Animation level. That way, you have a single complete "movie" that does your three animations in succession, and that *can* be easily repeated (it just repeats the whole "movie").

Comment: Look at this sample code - https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p148layerAnimation/ch17p490layerAnimation/ViewController.swift - in particular look at case 10 to see how to write a grouped animation that is a sequence of multiple animations. You could then set that grouped animation's `repeatCount` and you're done.

Comment: Yup, it's case 9 in this one: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch04p148layerAnimation/ch17p490layerAnimation/ViewController.m

Comment: Or you _could_ just read my book, it wouldn't kill you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_grouped_animations

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have worked out the obj c codes. However, there is a problem that as I need to change the text value of UIlabel in animations. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You're really not going to read any of my book are you? Sigh... Okay, look, each animation sends `animationDidStart:` and `animationDidStop:finished:` to its `delegate`, so if you have other things to do in time with an animation, that's your signal to do them. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_cabasicanimation_and_its_inheritance

Comment: Thanks Matt. yes I know that delegate will be called, but just want to see whether any simple solution similar to CATransction for an animation etc...

Comment: Ah. Well, the _transaction_ isn't going to help you because it doesn't end until the _whole_ animation ends.

Comment: But perhaps you meant a _transition_? Yes, you could certainly make a transition animation a part of your grouped animation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_transitions